# How to have an alert similar to Twitter Toast/Snackbar alert in Android Studio?

Tags: java, user-interface, android-notifications, android-toast, android-snackbar

How one can have Toast/Snackbar notification UI like  Twitter Toast/Snackbar  notification in android studio (java or kotlin)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the closest to your wanted Snakcbar is the following that you can find it in [this GitHub page (SnackbarUtils)](https://github.com/HuanHaiLiuXin/SnackbarUtils). (Author: HuanHaiLiuXin)
[image]